# getResourceAsStream return null when path changed

Tags: java, resources

Everything worked great until I moved the files to inner folder relatively to resources folder `/src/main/resources/settings`

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("./src/main/resources/settings"), path -> path.toFile().isFile())
    .forEach(value -> {
        if (value.toString().endsWith("properties")) {
            Properties currentProp = new Properties();
            try {
                currentProp.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(value.toFile().getName()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

`getResourceAsStream(value.toFile().getName())` - returns null

As said, if the files located directly in resources folder, all run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `getResourceAsStream` finds files relative to the classpath. Assuming that you folder structure is the standard maven one you would need to pass only `settings` to `Path.get`. With the code you have now it will look in `src/main/resources/src/main/resources/setting` and that is probably not what you want.